# Unity 2D for 12.10

Tags: 12.10, unity-2d

I'm using 12.10 with Unity 3D on my laptop and it's really laggy compared to when I used 12.04 with Unity 2D

How can I install Unity 2D for 12.10?

Comment: They removed unity 2d. I don't know if you can get it back. Try a different desktop environment like XFCE.

Comment: but I prefer Unity

Comment: Why can't you just purge unity3d from ubuntu 12.10 and install unity2d from [http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/unity-2d](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/unity-2d) via `gdebi-gtk` or `dpkg`. Another option would be to compile it from source.

Comment: can you please go into detail on how to do this? Since I'm completely clueless...

Answer (score 4):

Unity 2D has been removed ; in it's place, LLVMpipe is now used to perform the relevant shader operations on the CPU, in effect, taking the place of dedicated graphics hardware.

See ; http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTE2MTQ

This may work better on a 64-bit install, if you have the hardware, as noted in the article.

Answer (score 2):

There is a work around for those troubled by lags in Unity. For this, you need to add the following line in your `~/.xprofile` file. If the file doesn't exist, create it.

```
export UNITY_LOW_GFX_MODE=1
```

The line enables low graphics mode in Unity which disables some fancy effects like active blur and transparency.

Answer (score 0):

bro there is NO way you can purge unity 3d in ubuntu 13.04 cuz the unity2d package is DUMMY
you will have to install ubuntu 12.04 lts ( supported till april 2017)

-student

Answer (score -4):

try to run this code in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install llvm-dev
```

Comment: what does it do? will it install unity 2D?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd recommend installing LowLevelVirtualMachine in this case?